# Pass user's IP address to another web server

Tags: php, curl, nginx

I have 2 web servers, and at some time, web server A will need to request some data from web server B and for that it needs to send user's IP address. However, if I just call `file_get_contents()` on A server, B will detect IP address of server A and not from the user. Second option will be to pass IP address in query string, but nginx on server B is compiled with geoip module and i find country code in variable `$_SERVER['COUNTRY_CODE']`.

So my question, is there any way using CURL to pass user's IP address from server A to server B in the request? Probably I need to set some header and that header will be taken in consideration by geoip module?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://serverfault.com/questions/331079/haproxy-and-forwarding-client-ip-address-to-servers

Comment: Pass the IP as HTTP header, e.g. `X-Forwarded-For: {IP}`, to server B and make use of Nginx's RealIP module on server B. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this on server A:

```
curl www.domain.tld --header "X-Forwarded-For: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

You need to replace client IP with `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` on server A.

Depending on your application you may need to instruct it to validate `X-Forwarded-For` on server B.